# how to add datatable to dataset in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("MerchantName LIKE '%'", "MerchantName");

DataTable DataTable2 = new DataTable();
DataTable2 = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
foreach (DataRow dr in foundRows)
{
    DataTable2.ImportRow(dr);
}
ds.tables[0].rows.add(DataTable2); // error table already exists.
Loadimages(ds);
```

hi all,
upto foreach loop everything is working fine. In loadimages method i have to dataset. but i have the data in datatable. If i add datatable to dataset i am getting the error saying table already exists.
Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Downvote because having two of the same datatables in a dataset has to be a bad solution.

Answer (score 11):

I don't understand why you're trying to add a DataTable into another DataTable. Surely your code should be as follows:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("MerchantName LIKE '%'", "MerchantName");

DataTable DataTable2 = new DataTable();
DataTable2 = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
DataTable2.TableName = "DataTable2";
foreach (DataRow dr in foundRows)
{
    DataTable2.ImportRow(dr);
}
ds.Tables.Add(DataTable2); 
Loadimages(ds);
```

The reason for your error is because your `DataTables` within the `DataSet` must have unique names.

Comment: @Ibrahimkhan - Remember to accept the answer then. Click the tick next to the answer.

Comment: @ibrahimkhan - I'll chime in and say you should accept the answer as well. The link above has a screenshot, but all you need to do is click the checkmark outline for an answer that worked for you.